# What file permission should be set under directory Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

if I set the file permission under Wordpress to be 755, (this was recommended by Wordpress) it means the contents of wp_content, wp-includes, ... can be view and execute by the public, is it safe? Or can I take away the 'Read' by the public?  Also I have noticed that when I exit Wordpress, and go back to the site again (I didn't clicked remember me), I don't need to sign in again, can someone make use of the gap and go to the site without login? is clearing the Cache in Wordpress will solve this issue? Is there any plugin(s) help to do that? Thanks